# Какая есть обучающая литература по 2D графике directx

Tags: c#, книги

Мне нужна литература по работе с DirectX. Собственно, ничего стоящего так и не смог найти. Хотел бы узнать, есть какие-нибудь книги, уроки по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этой теме  какой-то вундеркинд отчаянно удаляет комментарии без явных на то причин. Поэтому напишу в виде ответа.

По сабжу. для C# не существует никаких официальных библиотек для работы с DirectX.
Была когда-то XNA, но ее разработка прекращена полтора года назад (впрочем, как таковой оберткой над DirectX он вроде бы не был).
  Есть несколько неофициальных (читай любительских) проектов, представляющий собой "рапперы" над нативным DirectX, те самые, о которых упоминал [[@Макс Жуков](/users/6941/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/6941/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). Пользоваться ими, разумеется, можно (и, вероятно, без особых последствий для собственной нервной системы), но рассчитывать на какую-либо литературу по ним было бы опрометчиво.

По поводу разработки игр на WPF - мой искренний вам совет - выкиньте эту безумную мысль из головы. WPF - это замечательная технология для разработки приложений с визуально привлекательными интерфейсами, векторной графикой, анимацией и прочими плюшками. Да, там есть возможности для работы с 3D-графикой, но сама эта технология не предназначена для разработки игр. Заложенные в нее средства ориентированы не на чистую графику, а на работу с элементами интерфейса. Разумеется, при наличии желания, упорства и, возможно, вкуса, можно создать что-то вменяемое (всякие там крестики-нолики уж точно), в конце концов есть люди, которые реализуют интернет-браузеры в консоли, но все же это скорее ради прикола, нежели реальная необходимость. ТО же самое и с играми на WPF - теоретически можно, но вряд ли будет разумным и рациональным. Словом, забивание гвоздей микроскопом.  Разумеется, книги по разработке игр на WPF - это что-то из области ненаучной фантастики.

Если же очень хочется заняться 3D-графикой применительно к разработке игр, то тут я вижу, пожалуй, два возможных пути:

1) перебраться с C# на С++ и засесть за DirectX. Информации по данной теме очень много, есть даже книги (даже российских авторов), есть DirectX SDK с десятками примеров (причем, очень даже способных впечатлить новичка)
Из минусов - придется отвыкнуть от удобного и стройного C# и привыкнуть к особенностям С++ и колориту DirectX SDK. Это может даться непросто. Можно также использовать и OPenGL (ситуация будет похожей)

2) можно использовать Unity 3D. О его преимуществах можно говорить много и долго (однако я не являюсь разработчиком Unity, поэтому особо разглагольствовать не рискну).  Из неоспоримых плюсов - разработка на том же C#, уже имеющийся редактор трехмерных сцен (без необходимости абсолютно все делать руками), огромное количество материалов, уроков, сайтов. Из минусов отмечу разве что цену (хотя все мы прекрасно понимаем, что небо не упадет на землю, если в целях обучения воспользоваться кряком) и отсутствие русскоязычной литературы (впрочем, обилие других источников это  компенсирует)

Comment: А, если пересесть на Java?

Comment: честно говоря, понятия не имею, что там на Java (скорее всего там предпочтительнее будет OpenGL)

@MadKeks, а почему вы так упорно избегаете Unity? ПО-моему, самый удобный и логичный вариант. Уж точно лучше, чем изобретать нежизнеспособные велосипеды с WPF

Comment: Я бы подумал о том, что бы изучить С++, если уж брать готовые движки и инструменты не хочется. А еще на всякий случай оставлю адрес на этот ресурс: [gcup.ru - портал посвященный созданию игр](http://gcup.ru/)

Comment: @DreamChild Пугает меня ваш Unity. Каждый 3-тий его использует.

Comment: @Alex Krass согласен, причем на мой взгляд имеет смысл изучить даже не конкретно С++, а теорию, связанную с двух- и трехмерной графикой. Заниматься этим всерьез, не имея хорошего математического базиса было бы опрометчиво, и нужно хотя бы в общих чертах знать о матричной математике, о том, как она связана с 3D-графикой. И для начала как раз стоило бы немного повозиться с низкоуровневыми вещами типа чистого DirectX SDK

Comment: >Пугает меня ваш Unity. Каждый 3-тий его использует

эмм..не понял..а вам нужен какой-то инструмент, которым никто не пользуется и по которому не найти никакой информации? А тем же WPF по-вашему никто не пользуется?

Comment: @DreamChild Ну не интересен мне Unity

Comment: @MadKeks ну это дело ваше, разумеется, хотя, конечно, такое отсутствие объективных причин несколько удивительно. Но в таком случае вам придется пользоваться куда менее удобными средствами и пвыполнять в десятки раз больше рутинной работы.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте wrapper'ы:

1. [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)
2. [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/)

Answer (score 4):

[[[[@MadKeks](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks), для DirectX нативная разработка ведется на С/С++. Все возможности разработки на managed-языках пришли от энтузиастов, поэтому форумы и коммьюнити по приведенным выше продуктам являются лучшими, если не единственными, источниками.

**Обновление**

[[[[@MadKeks](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks)](/users/20571/madkeks), скорее всего, вы почитали про "разработка приложений магазина Windows с использованием DirectX". Посмотрите сэмплы с msdn на эту тему.

Comment: Ну, а что тогда лучше использовать для разработки 2D/3D приложений на C#

Comment: @MadKeks, ну, например, Unity

Comment: @MadKeks, а что насчет WPF? Может он сможет помочь в реализации нужных задач. Основан на DirectX, имеет GPU ускорение.

Comment: @Alex Krass А литература, есть какая нибудь по разработке игр на WPF?

Comment: @MadKeks, по WPF есть только работа с графикой, алгоритмы для движка придется брать откуда-то еще:

- Jack Xu - Practical Wpf Graphics Programming
- Chris Sells - Programming WPF: Building Windows UI with Windows Presentation Foundation

Так же, наткнулся на амазоне на несколько книг по DirectX, может будут полезны:

- C# Game Programming: For Serious Game Creation by Daniel Schuller
- Beginning C# Game Programming by Ron Penton 
- Game Coding Complete, Fourth Edition by Mike McShaffry
- Visual C# Game Programming for Teens by Jonathan S. Harbour
- Game Engine Architecture by Jason Gregory

Comment: А вообще, если вы не хотите сильно заморачиваться с низкоуровневыми вещами для игродела, требующими хороших знаний физики и высшей математики, а так же порой разбирания кода алгоритма на другом языке(тот же с++), то советую просто взять движок для игр Unity, как говорили выше.

Answer (score 2):

Вот эту книгу читал когда-то: [Managed DirectX 9 с управляемым кодом. Программирование игр и графика (+ CD-ROM)](http://tfile.me/forum/viewtopic.php?t=553989)

> Книга позволяет изучить возможности использования Управляемого DirectX при разработке различных графических и мультимедийных приложений. В данной книге рассмотрены как основы программирования 3D-графики, так и более сложные разделы, например, управление уровнями детализации mesh-объектов, использование высокоуровневого языка шейдеров и символьной анимации. 
> В книге уделено достаточное внимание таким важным вопросам, как управление звуком и устройствами ввода или добавление звуковых эффектов и джойстика с обратной связью.